# Implementing Nested Traits

Tags: rust, traits

I have some traits which (after removing functions and some parameter bloat) look like:

```
trait Foo { }
trait Boo { }
trait Bar<T: Foo> { }
trait Baz { }
```

If `U` implements `Bar<T>` for some `T` implementing `Foo` *and* `U` implements `Boo`, then one is able to derive an implementation of `Baz` for `U`. However, I wasn't able to write valid Rust code doing this.

A few tries were:

```
impl<T: Foo, U: Bar<T> + Boo> Baz for U { }
```

which gives

> error: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates [E0207]

whereas

```
impl<U: Bar<T> + Boo> Baz for U { }
```

yields

> error: type name `T` is undefined or not in scope [E0412]

Could one/how could one do this in (stable) Rust (hopefully without any dynamic dispatch)?

**Edit**: Some people hinted at some similar questions for which there were essentially two approaches (and I find both of them unsuitable for my situation):

1. Using associated types. I don't want to do this because I want to keep track of `T`, e.g. I want to write some functions which have a signature like `fn bla<T: Foo, U: Bar<T>, V: Bar<T>>()` where I want to know that `U` and `V` implement `Bar<T>` for the *same* `T`. (Or is there way of doing this with associated types?)
2. Using some kind of wrapping by putting `U` and `T` in a struct. I don't want to use this either because I have several levels of such "trait dependencies", so wrapping things in each level would bloat the code a lot.

So the updated question would be: *Is there a solution to this problem without using associated types or wrappers?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it making `T` an associated type:

```
trait Foo { }
trait Boo { }
trait Bar {
    type T: Foo;
}
trait Baz { }

impl<U: Bar + Boo> Baz for U
    // this where clause is not necessary (this bound is already true)
    // where U::T: Foo
{ }
```

> I don't want to do this because I want to keep track of `T`, e.g. I want to write some functions which have a signature like `fn bla<T: Foo, U: Bar<T>, V: Bar<T>>()` where I want to know that `U` and `V` implement `Bar<T>` for the *same* `T`. (**Or is there way of doing this with associated types?**)

Yes, you can do it with associated types:

```
fn bla<U: Bar, V: Bar<T = U::T>>() { }
```